# Is the driver class (Main class) an association, aggregation, or composition?

Tags: java, oop, class, object, uml

I've been wondering what kind of relationship the main class (controlling all the other classes in a non-GUI program) has with the other classes?

for example a class which is instantiated in the class containing the main method and classes which the main method interacts with such as getting a return value.

EDIT: Should it even be included in the UML? because my professor includes it (I didn't even know it was called a driver class) and the book im reading apparently doesn't include it, no this isn't homework.

It could be an association because it interacts with it. It can also be an aggregation because its made up of several of a class. And a class doesn't make sense without it (in the program implementation) so I think its composition because composition is an aggregation and aggregation in turn is a type of association. Although several responses already posted sound like my answer is wrong.

Comment: What do you think yourself, and why do you think it? Since you know about the three terms, you probably know what each one of them mean also. (This sounds like homework, that's why I am asking this question)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg haha ive posted my answer although it seems i'm wrong because other responses said its none of them

Comment: Sorry for asking. I could tell after your first edit that this probably wasn't homework but a genuine interest. And a good question it is. +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of these. The main method is static. So it doesn't belong to any object. So you don't have any association. The main method *uses* instances of the other classes, that's all.

Comment: Say you had to make a UML class diagram for a console based TicTacToe game where the main method handled input. You would probably need it in the class diagram. You would have it in a sequence diagram as well for that matter.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You can't possibly need a class in the UML diagram that isn't even instantiated. That class simply does not partake in the aspect of the universe that the class diagram models.

Comment: I sometimes use UML to describe parts of a design which are better explained with a diagram than with code or a text description. And I don't care if the diagram doesn't represent exactly what the code does, because what matters to me is to show the big picture. If I really had to show that in a sequence diagram, I would probably use a fake object or actor named "main" in the sequence diagram. It would not appear in any class diagram.

Comment: You don't need to have instantiated a class to have it belong in a class diagram. Although it might not be OOP, you still do use some classes statically. A UML class diagram isn't a domain model diagram. It models the architecture and a starting point is part of the architecture. I agree with you if you only want to describe some logic in the design, but a full diagram should contain the main.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The UML class diagram (perhaps unfortunately) doesn't provide a way to model non-instances. One **may** misuse the formalism to get the important point across (UML should, after all, be about communication and not about formal specification), but as far as the formalism is concerned, and taught in university courses, that won't happen.

Comment: A UML **class** diagram shows relationships between classes, not instances.

Answer (score 3):

The main class doesn't have to be instantiated at all, so it doesn't necessarily belong anywhere in the UML diagram, but it **can** be instantiated and involved in any kind of relationship with the rest of the program. Both the book and your teacher may be right for their respective cases.

BTW don't confuse the associations between classes with what the `static` method `main` references. The `main` method itself is definitely **outside** the UML paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a kickstarter class, you can modify it to take any of these, but its better to keep it just for starter and build class paradigm out of it

Answer (score 1):

And about including it in UML - why not it should be included. Study about different design patterns - you will get to know about the relationship and there usages

this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643166/uml-how-do-i-do-this) might help you